# Magento 2 : How can we identify phpexecutable or not?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, cli, console

I'm working on creating custom console in which i have to add code that will check php is executable using below class. 
If **PHP** executable then which **PHP** version is executable.

**SyncCommand.php**

```
namespace Soft\Multi\Console\Command;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Shell;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList as DirectoryList;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;

use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder as PhpExeFinderFactory;

class SyncCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
            //accepting results of $pathToCallPHP variable as php71, php, php73 etc...
             $pathToCallPHP = $this->_phpExecutableFinder->getData();


    }
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="syncCommand" xsi:type="object">Soft\Multi\Console\Command\SyncCommand</item>
                </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check outputin console  `$output->writeln($pathToCallPHP)` I hope it's working for you.

```
class SyncCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
            //accepting results of $pathToCallPHP variable as php71, php, php73 etc...
             $pathToCallPHP = $this->_phpExecutableFinder->getData();
             $output->writeln($pathToCallPHP);     
    }
}
```